# jquery qtip2 : stop propagation option

Tags: javascript, qtip2

I have following structure

```
<div id="parent">
  Hello
  <div id="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I have jQuery qTip v2 plugin enabled in BOTH $('#parent') and $('#child') on click. But when I click on the child, the parent qtip is also displayed.

I guess I should use "event.stopPropagation()" or something similar, but how do I enable this in qtip?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by adding a click handler to the child that stops the event from propagating:

```
$('#child').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

qTip still gets the click event and displays the tooltip.